# Is it possible to operate the Panasonic GH1 via just the EVF if the LCD is broken?

Tags: panasonic, evf

Simple question for those who have used a GH1: Is it possible to fully operate the camera using just the EVF if the LCD is broken?  Or are some menu items only accessible on the LCD?

Answer (score 1):

I own a GH1. I just did a quick check. All display modes, except the "setting display" ([as shown here](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/DMCGH1/ZLCDRECINFO.GIF)) are duplicated on both, LCD and EVF.